WPF DataGrid ContextMenu shows up without right clicking the row
WPF application has 2 modes: basic and advanced.
There is a DataGrid where user can Rerun or Delete current item using context menu.
This context menu should only be available when advanced mode is active (Visibility and IsEnabled are bound to IsAdvancedMode property):
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsAdvancedMode, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Mode=OneWay,
      Converter={conv:BoolToVisibilityConverter VisibilityForFalse=Hidden}}"
      IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsAdvancedMode, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Mode=OneWay}">
.....
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>

Of course, Context menu is only supposed to show up when user right clicked on DataGrid row.
But it does show up when user switches from basic to advanced mode (by entering credentials in one of the application's dialog).
How to overcome this effect?


Let's skip to

How to overcome this effect?

If I understand your intent, you may want to hook the ContextMenuOpening event of the DataGrid and either mark it Handled or not, depending on the value of IsAdvancedMode. Marking it Handled will prevent the context menu from showing.

Code behind
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

    new MainWindowDataContext DataContext => (MainWindowDataContext)base.DataContext;

    private void ContextMenu_Opening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !DataContext.IsAdvancedMode;
    }
}


Xaml minimal reproducible example
<Window x:Class="wpf_context_menu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_context_menu"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:wpf_context_menu.Converters"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MenuDataContext x:Key="ProxyElement" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowDataContext />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid
            ItemsSource="{Binding JobItems}"
            ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_Opening"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            FontSize="16">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" />
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Name" Binding="{Binding JobName}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time" Binding="{Binding StartTime}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsAdvancedMode}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Is Advanced Mode" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


Data Context minimal reproducible example
partial class MainWindowDataContext : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isAdvancedMode;
    public ObservableCollection<JobItem> JobItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<JobItem>
    {
        new JobItem { JobName = "Data Backup", StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30), Status = Status.SUCCESS },
        new JobItem { JobName = "Data Analysis", StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60), Status = Status.FAILED },
        new JobItem { JobName = "Report Generation", StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-120), Status = Status.SUCCESS },
    };
}


This works. Somehow I forgot about ContextMenuOpening
